# GetDateFormatEx format string and custom text

Tags: mfc, date-formatting

Take this code:

```
GetDateFormatEx(_T("es"),
    NULL,
    &sysTime, 
    _T("d de MMMM"), 
    strDate.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH, nullptr);
```

I want it to come out as (for example):

> 5 de Enero

But I actually end up with:

> 5 5e Enero

How can we add our own custom text into the format string and get it to not be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the custom text inside single quotation marks like this:

```
"d 'de' MMMM"
```

More formatting details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/day--month--year--and-era-format-pictures). Quote:

> The application uses **single quotation marks to mark characters to
>   display exactly as specified**. If the application must display a single
>   quotation mark, it should place two single quotation marks in a row.
>   For example, `'abc''bar'`, is displayed as `"abc'bar"`.

Comment: Excellent. Most informative link. I found lots of places that showed the format codes but missed about the single. Works well now. Thanks again.